# Representation abelian subgroup of an abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let G a non abelian group of order $p^{3}$ and exponent $p$, where $p$ is a prime. Let $w$ be a primitive complex p-th root of unity.

So far, I have proved that:

- $Z(G)=[G:G]$
- $|Z(G)|=p$
- $G\cong \langle x,y,z\mid x^{p}=y^{p}=z^{p}=1, z=[x,y], [x,z], [y,z]\rangle$

How can I prove the next question?

1. Show that the abelian group $\langle x,z\rangle$ has a representation $X$ such that $X(z)=wI$ and $X(x)=diag(1,w,\ldots,w^{p-1})$.

Comment: This follows immediately from the fact that  the two proposed matrices for $X(z)$ and $X(x)$ commute and have order $p$.  Perhaps you are over-thinking it?

Comment: I can see that both matrices commute and have order p, but I don't understand how the primitive complex is related to both equations.

Comment: I don't know what you mean - what equations? The fact that the matrices commute and have order $p$ prove that this is a representation of the group $\langle x, z \rangle$, which has the presentation $\langle x,z \mid x^p=y^p=1, xz=zx \rangle$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I'm still working on $X(x)=diag(1,w,...,w^{p-1})$ but I understand the first part.